# ffmpeg not copying FRONT_COVER image metadata during conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, file-metadata, id3

When doing an mp3 → mp3 (or flac → mp3) conversion, `-map_metadata` can be used to copy metadata from the input file to the output file:

```bsh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -nostats -i "${source}" -map_metadata 0 -vn -ar 44100 -b:a 256k -f mp3 "${target}"
```

However, when I use this, I notice that it doesn't copy all the metadata correctly. Using the tool [`eyeD3`](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I inspecting the input and output files see this:

```
$ eyeD3 input.mp3 
input.mp3  [ 4.15 MB ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 01:46 MPEG1, Layer III    [ 320 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Stereo ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.3:
title: Track title
artist: Artist Name
album: Album Name
album artist: Various Artists
composer: Composer Name
recording date: 2019
eyed3.id3:WARNING: Non standard genre name: Soundtracks
track: 17/37        genre: Soundtracks (id None)
disc: 1/1
FRONT_COVER Image: [Size: 86555 bytes] [Type: image/jpeg]
Description: 

PRIV: [Data: 42 bytes]
Owner Id: Google/StoreId
PRIV: [Data: 40 bytes]
Owner Id: Google/StoreLabelCode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ eyeD3 path/to/output.mp3 
/tmp/test.mp3                                                       [ 3.26 MB ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Time: 01:46 MPEG1, Layer III    [ 256 kb/s @ 44100 Hz - Stereo ]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID3 v2.4:
title: Track title
artist: Artist Name
album: Album Name
album artist: Various Artists
composer: Composer Name
recording date: 2019
eyed3.id3:WARNING: Non standard genre name: Soundtracks
track: 17/37        genre: Soundtracks (id None)
disc: 1/1
PRIV: [Data: 40 bytes]
Owner Id: Google/StoreLabelCode
PRIV: [Data: 42 bytes]
Owner Id: Google/StoreId
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Specifically, it's not copying the `FRONT_COVER` image correctly - somehow it's being dropped along the way.

**How can I ensure that the `FRONT_COVER Image` is copied during the conversion process?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front cover is treated as a video stream with a special disposition. Use of `-vn` will disable its processing.

Use
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -nostats -i "${source}" -map_metadata 0 -c:v copy -disposition:v:0 attached_pic -ar 44100 -b:a 256k -f mp3 "${target}"`

Comment: Oh, that's weird - I didn't know that! That seems to work as intended: I've marked it as the accepted answer. Thanks!